# CSS свойство cursor работает иначе в полноэкранном режиме с SVG

Tags: css, svg, vue.js

Делаю кастомные элементы управления на `video`. Для иконок использую svg. В обычном режиме(не полноэкранном) css-свойство `cursor: pointer`(я поставил его `div`-контейнеру, в котором находится svg) работает на всю область иконки, также на всю область работает и событие `onclick`. Но когда я перехожу в полноэкранный режим `video` свойство `cursor` и событие клика работает только непосредственно на гранях путей(`path`) svg-элемента, а пространство между ними неактивно. Мне нужно чтобы в полноэкранном режиме свойство `cursor:pointer` и событие `onclick` работали на всей области элемента, а не только на гранях.

Вот так выглядит мой `html`:

```
<div class="custom-video-container">
    <video :src="src" class="custom-video" ref="video"></video>
    <div class="video-play-button" ref="play" :class="{removed: videoStopped}">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" @click="playVideo">
            <path d="M424.4 214.7L72.4 6.6C43.8-10.3 0 6.1 0 47.9V464c0 37.5 40.7 60.1 72.4 41.3l352-208c31.4-18.5 31.5-64.1 0-82.6z"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="bot-menu" ref="menu" :class="{removed: videoStopped == false}">
        <div class="svg-container" @click="switchVideo">
            <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="svg">
                <path v-if="videoPlaying" class="ytp-svg-fill" d="M 12,26 16,26 16,10 12,10 z M 21,26 25,26 25,10 21,10 z">
                    <animate ref="anime" class="but-play" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" dur=".2s" begin="none" fill="freeze" from="M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22 25,18 25,18 18.5,14 z" to="M 12,26 16,26 16,10 12,10 z M 21,26 25,26 25,10 21,10 z" />
                </path>
                <path v-else class="ytp-svg-fill" d="M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22 25,18 25,18 18.5,14 z">
                    <animate ref="anime" class="but-play" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" dur=".2s" begin="none" fill="freeze" from="M 12,26 16,26 16,10 12,10 z M 21,26 25,26 25,10 21,10 z" to="M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22 25,18 25,18 18.5,14 z" />
                </path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="bot-menu-icon-wrap">
            <div class="svg-container">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
                style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve" class="svg svg-map">
                    <path d="M60.6,30c0-5.5-4.5-10-10.1-10c-5.6,0-10.1,4.5-10.1,10s4.5,10,10.1,10C56.1,40,60.6,35.5,60.6,30z M44.4,30  c0-3.3,2.7-6,6.1-6s6.1,2.7,6.1,6s-2.7,6-6.1,6S44.4,33.3,44.4,30z M50,64.8l1.4-1.4C67.9,47.1,69.2,35.2,69.2,32v-2  c0-10.5-8.6-19-19.2-19s-19.2,8.5-19.2,19v2c0,3.2,1.3,15.1,17.8,31.4L50,64.8z M34.8,30c0-8.3,6.8-15,15.2-15  c8.4,0,15.2,6.7,15.2,15v2c0,2-0.8,12.3-15.2,27.1C35.6,44.3,34.8,33.9,34.8,32V30z M94.8,75.7L72.7,89l-22.4-7.4  c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.5-0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3L26.9,89L4.8,75.7l11.9-42.9L29,40.2c1,0.6,1.3,1.8,0.7,2.7  c-0.6,0.9-1.8,1.2-2.8,0.7L19.2,39L9.5,73.8L26,83.8l3.8-33c0.1-1.1,1.1-1.9,2.2-1.8c1.1,0.1,1.9,1.1,1.8,2.2l-3.8,32.5L48,77.8  c0,0,0,0,0,0v-6.9c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2v7c0,0,0,0,0,0L70,83.9l-3.8-32.7c-0.1-1.1,0.7-2.1,1.8-2.2  c1.1-0.1,2.1,0.7,2.2,1.8L74,83.5l16.1-9.7L80.4,39l-7.7,4.6c-1,0.6-2.2,0.3-2.8-0.7c-0.6-0.9-0.3-2.2,0.7-2.7l12.3-7.4L94.8,75.7z"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="svg-container" @click="switchFullscreen">
                <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="svg svg-expand">
                    <g class="ytp-fullscreen-button-corner-0">
                        <path class="ytp-svg-fill" d="m 10,16 2,0 0,-4 4,0 0,-2 L 10,10 l 0,6 0,0 z" id="ytp-id-23"></path>
                    </g>
                    <g class="ytp-fullscreen-button-corner-1">
                        <path class="ytp-svg-fill" d="m 20,10 0,2 4,0 0,4 2,0 L 26,10 l -6,0 0,0 z" id="ytp-id-24"></path>
                    </g>
                    <g class="ytp-fullscreen-button-corner-2">
                        <path class="ytp-svg-fill" d="m 24,24 -4,0 0,2 L 26,26 l 0,-6 -2,0 0,4 0,0 z" id="ytp-id-25"></path>
                    </g>
                    <g class="ytp-fullscreen-button-corner-3">
                        <path class="ytp-svg-fill" d="M 12,20 10,20 10,26 l 6,0 0,-2 -4,0 0,-4 0,0 z" id="ytp-id-26"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Это `css`, который относится к панели управления видео:

```
.bot-menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .2s;
    z-index: 2147483647;
}

.custom-video-container:hover .bot-menu {
    opacity: 1;
}

.svg {
    height: 100%;
    fill: #fff;
    transition: .2s;
}

.svg-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Это JS, которым я вхожу и выхожу из полноэкранного режима:

```
switchFullscreen() {
    var elem = this.$refs.video;
    var isFullscreen = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    if(isFullscreen) {
        if (elem.exitFullScreen) {
          elem.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitExitFullScreen) {
          elem.webkitExitFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.mozExitFullScreen) {
          elem.mozExitFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.oExitFullScreen) {
            elem.oExitFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.msExitFullScreen) {
            elem.msExitFullScreen();
        }
    } else {
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
          elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }
},
```